# Set attributes of one triple nested list to another triple nested list in R

Tags: r, list

I would like to set the attributes of one triple nested list to the attributes of another triple nested list.

Here is a triple nested list:

```
list.A <- list(a = c(1,2,5,6), b = c(2,4,6,5), c = c(2,4,2,5))
list.B <- list(a = c(7,7,7,7), b = c(8,8,8,8), c = c(9,9,9,9))
weights <- list(list.A, list.B)
names(weights) <- c("list.A", "list.B")

list.A <- list(a = c(2,2,2,2), b = c(3,3,3,3), c = c(4,4,4,4))
list.B <- list(a = c(5,5,5,5), b = c(6,6,6,6), c = c(7,7,7,7))
scores <- list(list.A, list.B)
names(scores) <- c("list.A", "list.B")

megalist <- list(weights, scores)
names(megalist) <- c("weights", "scores")
megalist

> megalist
$weights
$weights$list.A
$weights$list.A$a
[1] 1 2 5 6

$weights$list.A$b
[1] 2 4 6 5

$weights$list.A$c
[1] 2 4 2 5


$weights$list.B
$weights$list.B$a
[1] 7 7 7 7

$weights$list.B$b
[1] 8 8 8 8

$weights$list.B$c
[1] 9 9 9 9



$scores
$scores$list.A
$scores$list.A$a
[1] 2 2 2 2

$scores$list.A$b
[1] 3 3 3 3

$scores$list.A$c
[1] 4 4 4 4


$scores$list.B
$scores$list.B$a
[1] 5 5 5 5

$scores$list.B$b
[1] 6 6 6 6

$scores$list.B$c
[1] 7 7 7 7
```

Here are the attributes for `megalist[["weights"]]$list.A`, and they are the same for `megalist[["scores"]]$list.A`.

```
attributes(megalist[["weights"]]$list.A)
$names
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Here is the triple nested list `microlist` whose attributes of `list.A` I want to assign to `megalist` `list.A`:

```
list.A <- list(a = c(3,3,3,3), b = c(4,4,4,4), c = c(5,5,5,5))
list.B <- list(a = c(1,1,1,1), b = c(2,2,2,2), c = c(8,8,8,8))
weights <- list(list.A, list.B)
names(weights) <- c("list.A", "list.B")

list.A <- list(a = c(9,9,9,9), b = c(7,7,7,7), c = c(2,2,2,2))
list.B <- list(a = c(4,4,4,4), b = c(2,2,2,2), c = c(6,6,6,6))
scores <- list(list.A, list.B)
names(scores) <- c("list.A", "list.B")

microlist <- list(weights, scores)
names(microlist) <- c("weights", "scores")
microlist

> microlist
$weights
$weights$list.A
$weights$list.A$a
[1] 3 3 3 3

$weights$list.A$b
[1] 4 4 4 4

$weights$list.A$c
[1] 5 5 5 5


$weights$list.B
$weights$list.B$a
[1] 1 1 1 1

$weights$list.B$b
[1] 2 2 2 2

$weights$list.B$c
[1] 8 8 8 8



$scores
$scores$list.A
$scores$list.A$a
[1] 9 9 9 9

$scores$list.A$b
[1] 7 7 7 7

$scores$list.A$c
[1] 2 2 2 2


$scores$list.B
$scores$list.B$a
[1] 4 4 4 4

$scores$list.B$b
[1] 2 2 2 2

$scores$list.B$c
[1] 6 6 6 6
```

Here are the attributes of `microlist` `list.A` that I want to set for `megalist` `list.A`:

```
attributes(microlist[["weights"]]$list.A)["class"] <- "nb"
attributes(microlist[["scores"]]$list.A)["class"]  <- "nb"

attributes(microlist[["weights"]]$list.A)["region.id"] <- list(c("1","2","3"))
attributes(microlist[["scores"]]$list.A)["region.id"]  <- list(c("1","2","3"))

attributes(microlist[["weights"]]$list.A)["call"] <- "dnearneigh(x = coord.mat, d1 = 0, d2 = (1 + sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) * 
    lowlim)"
attributes(microlist[["scores"]]$list.A)["call"]  <- "dnearneigh(x = coord.mat, d1 = 0, d2 = (1 + sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) * 
    lowlim)"

attributes(microlist[["weights"]]$list.A)["dnn"] <- list(c(0.0000, 137.4062))
attributes(microlist[["scores"]]$list.A)["dnn"]  <- list(c(0.0000, 137.4062))

attributes(microlist[["weights"]]$list.A)["bounds"] <- list(c("GE","LE"))
attributes(microlist[["scores"]]$list.A)["bounds"]  <- list(c("GE","LE"))

attributes(microlist[["weights"]]$list.A)["nbtype"] <- "distance"
attributes(microlist[["scores"]]$list.A)["nbtype"]  <- "distance"

attributes(microlist[["weights"]]$list.A)["sym"] <- TRUE
attributes(microlist[["scores"]]$list.A)["sym"]  <- TRUE

attributes(microlist[["weights"]]$list.A)["names"] <- list(c("a","b","c"))
attributes(microlist[["scores"]]$list.A)["names"]  <- list(c("a","b","c"))

attributes(microlist[["weights"]]$list.A)
attributes(microlist[["scores"]]$list.A) 
##the attributes for weights and scores list.A are the same

> attributes(microlist[["scores"]]$list.A)
$names
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$class
[1] "nb"

$region.id
[1] "1" "2" "3"

$call
[1] "dnearneigh(x = coord.mat, d1 = 0, d2 = (1 + sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) * \n    lowlim)"

$dnn
[1]   0.0000 137.4062

$bounds
[1] "GE" "LE"

$nbtype
[1] "distance"

$sym
[1] TRUE
```

I have tried this:

```
megalist.attrib <- lapply(megalist, function(x, new) {
  attributes(x[["list.A"]]) <- new
  x
}, new = lapply(microlist, function(y) {
  attributes(y[["list.A"]]) 
  y}))
```

but it returns a summary of the attributes for each nested list rather than the same attributes as `microlist` `list.A`:

```
> attributes(megalist.attrib[["weights"]]$list.A)
$weights
Characteristics of weights list object:
Neighbour list object:
Number of regions: 3 
Number of nonzero links: 2 
Percentage nonzero weights: 66
Average number of links: 1 

$scores
Characteristics of scores list object:
Neighbour list object:
Number of regions: 3 
Number of nonzero links: 1 
Percentage nonzero weights: 33 
Average number of links: 1
```

In my real problem, the attribute types and values change across lists so I am hoping to find a way that is less about hard coding the text and more about changing the attributes of `megalist` to be those of `microlist`, so above is just an example.

Comment: you did not elaborate on what you want to change. ie what should your final result look like?

Comment: @onyambu I edited the post to be more clear and what the desired output should look like and how that informs the answer to the question.

Comment: Still incomplete.`Megalist` contains `listA` and the available `attributes` within `listA` is just the names ie `a,b,c,d` On the other hand, `microlist` does not have `listA`. So what are you changing?

Comment: @onyambu Sorry for the confusion. The lists ```megalist``` and ```microlist``` have the same structure, with ```weights``` and ```scores``` as nested lists, with ```list.A``` and ```list.B``` nested within those, and with lists ```a```, ```b```, and ```c``` nested within those. The differences are the attributes of ```microlist```: either ```weights``` or ```scores``` lists: ```list.A``` that I would like to use to replace the attributes of ```megalist```: either ```weights``` or ```scores``` lists: ```list.A```. I welcome any further clarification I can add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a fairly simple `for` loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(microlist)) {
  attributes(megalist[[i]]$list.A) <- attributes(microlist[[i]]$list.A)
}
```

Or using `purrr::map2()`:

```
library(purrr)

megalist <- map2(megalist, microlist, ~ { 
  attributes(.x$list.A) <- attributes(.y$list.A) 
  .x
})
```

Results in either case:

```
#> megalist
$weights
$weights$list.A
$a
[1] 1 2 5 6

$b
[1] 2 4 6 5

$c
[1] 2 4 2 5

attr(,"class")
[1] "nb"
attr(,"region.id")
[1] "1" "2" "3"
attr(,"call")
[1] "dnearneigh(x = coord.mat, d1 = 0, d2 = (1 + sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) * \n    lowlim)"
attr(,"dnn")
[1]   0.0000 137.4062
attr(,"bounds")
[1] "GE" "LE"
attr(,"nbtype")
[1] "distance"
attr(,"sym")
[1] TRUE

$weights$list.B
$weights$list.B$a
[1] 7 7 7 7

$weights$list.B$b
[1] 8 8 8 8

$weights$list.B$c
[1] 9 9 9 9



$scores
$scores$list.A
$a
[1] 2 2 2 2

$b
[1] 3 3 3 3

$c
[1] 4 4 4 4

attr(,"class")
[1] "nb"
attr(,"region.id")
[1] "1" "2" "3"
attr(,"call")
[1] "dnearneigh(x = coord.mat, d1 = 0, d2 = (1 + sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) * \n    lowlim)"
attr(,"dnn")
[1]   0.0000 137.4062
attr(,"bounds")
[1] "GE" "LE"
attr(,"nbtype")
[1] "distance"
attr(,"sym")
[1] TRUE

$scores$list.B
$scores$list.B$a
[1] 5 5 5 5

$scores$list.B$b
[1] 6 6 6 6

$scores$list.B$c
[1] 7 7 7 7
```

Answer (score 1):

`modifyList(microlist, megalist)` should work, it takes a nested list and replaces elements with the ones provided in the second argument. If you have the same names on both sides, as is the case in the provided data, it will update all the values but keep the attributes of the lists.

```r
microlist <- list(
  weights = list(
    list.A = list(a = c(3, 3, 3, 3), b = c(4, 4, 4, 4), c = c(5, 5, 5, 5)) |>
      structure(
        class = "nb",
        region.id = c("1", "2", "3"),
        call = "dnearneigh(x = coord.mat, d1 = 0, d2 = (1 + sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) * \n    lowlim)",
        dnn = c(0, 137.4062),
        bounds = c("GE", "LE"),
        nbtype = "distance",
        sym = TRUE
      ),
    list.B = list(a = c(1, 1, 1, 1), b = c(2, 2, 2, 2), c = c(8, 8, 8, 8))
  ),
  scores = list(
    list.A = list(a = c(9, 9, 9, 9), b = c(7, 7, 7, 7), c = c(2, 2, 2, 2)) |>
      structure(
        class = "nb",
        region.id = c("1", "2", "3"),
        call = "dnearneigh(x = coord.mat, d1 = 0, d2 = (1 + sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) * \n    lowlim)",
        dnn = c(0, 137.4062),
        bounds = c("GE", "LE"),
        nbtype = "distance",
        sym = TRUE
      ),
    list.B = list(a = c(4, 4, 4, 4), b = c(2, 2, 2, 2), c = c(6, 6, 6, 6))
  )
)

megalist <- list(
  weights = list(
    list.A = list(a = c(1, 2, 5, 6), b = c(2, 4, 6, 5), c = c(2, 4, 2, 5)),
    list.B = list(a = c(7, 7, 7, 7), b = c(8, 8, 8, 8), c = c(9, 9, 9, 9))
  ),
  scores = list(
    list.A = list(a = c(2, 2, 2, 2), b = c(3, 3, 3, 3), c = c(4, 4, 4, 4)),
    list.B = list(a = c(5, 5, 5, 5), b = c(6, 6, 6, 6), c = c(7, 7, 7, 7))
  )
)

wish <- list(
  weights = list(
    list.A = list(a = c(1, 2, 5, 6), b = c(2, 4, 6, 5), c = c(2, 4, 2, 5)) |>
      structure(
        class = "nb",
        region.id = c("1", "2", "3"),
        call = "dnearneigh(x = coord.mat, d1 = 0, d2 = (1 + sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) * \n    lowlim)",
        dnn = c(0, 137.4062),
        bounds = c("GE", "LE"),
        nbtype = "distance",
        sym = TRUE
      ),
    list.B = list(a = c(7, 7, 7, 7), b = c(8, 8, 8, 8), c = c(9, 9, 9, 9))
  ),
  scores = list(
    list.A = list(a = c(2, 2, 2, 2), b = c(3, 3, 3, 3), c = c(4, 4, 4, 4)) |>
      structure(
        class = "nb",
        region.id = c("1", "2", "3"),
        call = "dnearneigh(x = coord.mat, d1 = 0, d2 = (1 + sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) * \n    lowlim)",
        dnn = c(0, 137.4062),
        bounds = c("GE", "LE"),
        nbtype = "distance",
        sym = TRUE
      ),
    list.B = list(a = c(5, 5, 5, 5), b = c(6, 6, 6, 6), c = c(7, 7, 7, 7))
  )
)


new_mega_list <- modifyList(microlist, megalist)

identical(new_mega_list, wish)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Session info (edited)

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
#>  os       macOS Monterey 12.0.1
#>  system   aarch64, darwin20
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8
#>  tz       Europe/Zurich
#>  date     2022-11-30
#> ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: @simpson is this not the desired output ?

Comment: It is the desired output. However, just typing ```modifyList(microlist, megalist)``` generates the error: ```Error in card(nb) : 
  INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'double'```. This has to do with the attributes in ```microlist``` ```list.A```, I think. So, what you listed is the desired output, but my session threw an error.

Comment: Is this when you test it on your real data or when you test in on the sample data you gave here ?

Comment: This error is generated on the sample data here. When I view ```list.A``` of either ```megalist``` or ```microlist```, ```list.A```  does contain lists of ```double``` class, if that helps.

Comment: This is very surprising, see my edit, easier to reproduce, can you copy and paste it, run it and report ?

Comment: ```> sessioninfo::session_info()

[1] /nfs/home/simpson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0
[2] /opt/R/4.0.4/lib/R/library``` I cannot report all the output, because the packages and versions are too long for a comment. Does this help?

Comment: It's useful but I mainly wanted to know if running my answer complete with data definition failed.

Comment: Yes, running your answer with your data definition worked. I wonder why it didn't work on my end.

Answer (score 0):

If the two lists' structures are the same, then the following might work.

```
mapply(\(x, y) {
  attributes(x[["list.A"]]) <- attributes(y[["list.A"]])
  x
}, megalist, microlist)
```

Comment: Indeed, that does work to set the attributes of one nested list to another. But because it's ```mapply```, it changes everything else about the structure of the object. I am wondering if there is a way to keep everything else the same and just change the attributes of one nested list to another.

Comment: @simpson I couldn't test since there is no reproducible `microlist`. Can you post a small example list?

Comment: I updated the Question to be fully reproducible now with full code for ```microlist``` and the code I used to assign the attributes to ```microlist``` ```list.A``` for this Question.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying manually manipulate the `listw` object from `{spdep}`. If you shared 1) a reproducible example and 2) what your actual objective is (e.g. manually modify weights list elements) this would be easier to answer.

The below should do what I understand you want to do (if I do understand indeed!).

You take the naes of the attributes from your second list, then you assign based on a subset of those attributes in nb1.

```r
library(spdep)
#> Loading required package: sp
#> Loading required package: spData
#> To access larger datasets in this package, install the spDataLarge
#> package with: `install.packages('spDataLarge',
#> repos='https://nowosad.github.io/drat/', type='source')`
#> Loading required package: sf
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.2.3, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

columbus <- st_read(
  system.file("shapes/columbus.shp", package="spData")[1],
  quiet=TRUE
)


nb1 <- poly2nb(columbus)
nb2 <-  knn2nb(knearneigh(st_centroid(columbus), k = 3))
#> Warning in st_centroid.sf(columbus): st_centroid assumes attributes are constant
#> over geometries of x


# If you want to overwrite attributes to be exactly that from the other list
attributes(nb1) <- attributes(nb2)

identical(attributes(nb1), attributes(nb2))
#> [1] TRUE

attributes(nb1)
#> $region.id
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15"
#> [16] "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "29" "30"
#> [31] "31" "32" "33" "34" "35" "36" "37" "38" "39" "40" "41" "42" "43" "44" "45"
#> [46] "46" "47" "48" "49"
#> 
#> $call
#> knearneigh(x = st_centroid(columbus), k = 3)
#> 
#> $sym
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> $type
#> [1] "knn"
#> 
#> $`knn-k`
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $class
#> [1] "nb"
attributes(nb2)
#> $region.id
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15"
#> [16] "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "29" "30"
#> [31] "31" "32" "33" "34" "35" "36" "37" "38" "39" "40" "41" "42" "43" "44" "45"
#> [46] "46" "47" "48" "49"
#> 
#> $call
#> knearneigh(x = st_centroid(columbus), k = 3)
#> 
#> $sym
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> $type
#> [1] "knn"
#> 
#> $`knn-k`
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $class
#> [1] "nb"

# If you want all of nb1 attributes AND nb2 attributes
# where you overwrite matches from nb1 and nb2 with values from nb2
nb1 <- poly2nb(columbus)

nb2_attr_names <- names(attributes(nb2))

attributes(nb1)[nb2_attr_names] <- attributes(nb2)

attributes(nb1)
#> $class
#> [1] "nb"
#> 
#> $region.id
#>  [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15"
#> [16] "16" "17" "18" "19" "20" "21" "22" "23" "24" "25" "26" "27" "28" "29" "30"
#> [31] "31" "32" "33" "34" "35" "36" "37" "38" "39" "40" "41" "42" "43" "44" "45"
#> [46] "46" "47" "48" "49"
#> 
#> $call
#> knearneigh(x = st_centroid(columbus), k = 3)
#> 
#> $type
#> [1] "knn"
#> 
#> $sym
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> $`knn-k`
#> [1] 3
```

Comment: Indeed, my real problem is taking the result of the ```listw.candidates``` function from the ```adespatial``` package where I modified the nested lists in the result object and ultimately lost the attributes. To stick my ```listw.candidates``` result devoid of special attributes into the ```listw.select``` function yields an error that I have narrowed down to the source code of the ```spdep``` package where the internal workings read the attributes. So, I am trying to stick the attributes from my original ```listw.candidates``` result into my modified ```listw.candidates``` result.

Comment: Your answer works as long as the lists are not nested. The resulting object of the ```listw.candidates``` function contains the object name, within which are multiple lists containing models like ```dnearest neighbor```, ```Delaunay triangulation```, etc., within which are the ```neighbours``` and ```weights``` lists. Within the ```neighbours``` list are multiple lists. In the real problem, I am trying to work with the lists within the ```neighbours``` list, which are akin to the lists within ```list.A``` in my posted example. Subsetting the nested lists is key to assign attributes.